Coordinate system for describing 3D target position relative to plane FRD
I'm trying to understand what is the most popular convention for describing the position of a point in 3D space relative to a plane's body frame, with axis "front", "right" and "down" (FRD).
In mathematics I know that it's popular to use the spherical coordinate system (polar angle, azimuthal angle, distance), but the "polar angle" seems to be inconvenient (a point in front of the plane would have a polar angle of pi/2). Is the elevation angle more often used instead of the polar angle?
The tuple (elevation angle, polar angle, distance) have the nice property that a target in front of the plane has angles 0 and 0. But assuming that the Z axis is "down", the name "elevation angle" seems to be misleading (when the Z axis is "down", a positive angle would mean "down", which doesn't seem to describe "elevation"). Therefore this approach also doesn't seem "right" (although mostly because of the name "elevation").
What is the most practical and intuitive coordinate system used in aviation for describing a 3D point position?

For what purpose, and by whom?

A positive elevation angle (positive rotation around the Y axis) is up, not down. Apply the right hand rule of rotation (stretched out thumb, curled fist) to the Y axis.

"Popular" depends on your target audience and how they use that information. If your audience is a developper team for flight simulation, the "Z down axis" is an endless debate and has no conclusive preference; it all comes down to 3D transformation matrices so everyone just cope with whatever data comes. For instance, PBA locally known as Pitch/Bank/Angle assumes Y pointing up and Z pointing right wing or the other way around. Then various tools usually uses different reference models, transformations is most likely always the answer. I second Michael : purpose, by whom, and for whom ?

The most common, from a pilot's experience, is clock position, range, and relative altitude: "Traffic at 2 o'clock and 9 miles, 1,000' above your altitude."
Everything else is easily converted to whatever reference frame best facilitates the needed computations or is most intelligible to the audience, whether that is an X-Y-Z coordinate system, or angles, or whatever else.
